# RTK Query prevent data.data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I'm following RTK Query tutorial at `https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript`.

I have the following endpoint:

```
const myApi = myBaseApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: build => ({
        myMethod: build.query<MyClass, void>({
            query: () => 'path/to/endpoint',
        }),
    }),
    overrideExisting: false,
});
```

However when I use the hook for this query like below:

`const q = useMyMethod()`

`q.data` is strongly typed to `MyClass` which is perfect. *However* when I run the app, `q.data` is a fetch response object, with another `data` property which actually is the `MyClass` instance. In other words, I need to type `q.data.data` to access the actual data. In the examples this isn't the case. What am I doing wrong and how can I access `q.data` as `MyClass` directly without involving fetch response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a "fetch response" object.  The query hooks return an object that contains the actual fetched and cached value as `data`, plus a number of status flag fields:

```
const { data , isFetching } = useSomeQuery()
```

See the list of fields here:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#frequently-used-query-hook-return-values

If you're saying that there's *another* `data` field nested inside, then that's likely coming from your actual API response, because RTKQ just saves whatever value your API response returned.  I'd suggest checking both the server side and the network response tab to see what's being returned from the server.

Also, the expectation is that the fetched value is plain JS objects and arrays.  When you say `MyClass`, that makes it sound like you expect this to be an actual JS class *instance*, and RTKQ will definitely not create a class instance for you - it just does the usual `fetch().then(r => r.json())` processing for you.

Comment: Yup, it was _another_ data inside data and it was exactly what you said. The response has a data, status etc fields which mimic fetch response. As I'm new to both RTK Query _and_ the API that I'm working with I thought it was a fetch response. RTK Query hook had a data field that contained the response, which, then had another data field in itself with the actual data. I'll be using `transformResponse` to extract and return the actual data field from the object. Thanks!

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu could you share your code, how you did the transform ?  Thanks.